# Creating iPhone Apps Generator i.e creating iPhone applications automatically.

Tags: iphone, generator

I am working on an application to create Magazine in iPad- iPhone. The template is ready but now I want to make an automator on web interface where user who wants an application for his/her magazine can input the contents and details required by the template of magazine and gets his .ipa for magazine done. Something like this [13 tools](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/13_tools_for_building_your_own_iphone_app.php) does.

I tried to find the working of these tools but found nothing. I wish to know if its possible to create this kind of tools? Is there any Apple script to create some kind of bash file or plist file that can help to do this?

Please suggest what approach can be followed to create such tools.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Did you find any solution or any resource which would point us to solution. If so, Please share your answer. Thanks

Comment: I have not found any solutions yet but I have got some shell script and I am thinking to execute this shell script from PHP execute function. I am not sure how it will work for me.